# selenium grid specify platform

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm using official selenium grid & nodes images from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium with JAVA's remote webdriver.

Is it possible to force the node to run chrome browsers on windows? or at least behave as if it were?

Tried to set the cabilities in node's config (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/NodeChrome/generate_config) and rebuild the images.

```
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "platform": "WIN10",
      "version": "$CHROME_VERSION",
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": $NODE_MAX_INSTANCES,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "applicationName": "$NODE_APPLICATION_NAME"
    }
  ]
```

In this case - no effect (no errors ether. just keeps using `platform: 'LINUX'`).

and tried to specify browser's capabilities, such as `capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);` - in this case getting an error `Unable to create session` without the particular case, but i guess the case is the platform capability option.

Any advise?

Comment: where is your node running, is it on windows or linux?

Comment: on linux    //////

Comment: Then it's expected behavior, as selenium can not create the session windows platform session on linux box. Create a node in windows box and then try to create the instance with platform.

Comment: ok, got it, so it is expected. thank you.

Comment: @supputuri - Can we edit the platform name using env value in the deployment YAML file for docker so that we get Windows Platform. If yes what will be the key for platorm

Answer (score 2):

"platform": "WIN10"

does not exist.

You can check here the documentation on DesiredCapabilites.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

These platforms are available and supported by selenium:

```
{WINDOWS, XP, VISTA, MAC, LINUX, UNIX, ANDROID}
```

In your particular case, if you want windows, change your platform to `"WINDOWS", "XP" or "VISTA"`

Also this link might be useful for you:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid-Platforms

Comment: yeah seems like i'm overseen this - just copyed from `Platform` class. But in any case i have to run grid on windows server, no?

Comment: It depends on your needs, selenium grid supports windows nodes inside a docker container, but you need to specify it in the config because the default platform on selenium grid is linux.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification. Once you launch your node, go back to Hub console `http://localhost:4444/grid/console` and then check the browser configuration. You can use those them in the capabilities while creating the Remote Driver instance.

[image]

Comment: yeah i know that. initially my question was if i'm able to change those without changing the real OS.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to add more information so that it helps anyone not sure how to use the capabilities based on based on hub-node combination.